# Azure: copy console application.exe.config (generated from app.config) to Azure package

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I have a console application that gets started as a `background` `Startup Task`  before the role starts. I referenced the console application from the Role Project.

In the console application's app.config i have some Log4Net configuration. The `MyApplication.exe` and `app.config`(which is set to `always copy`)  get copied to the azure package but the `MyApplication.exe.config` doesn't get copied so Log4Net configuration fails.

Why isn't the .exe.config doesn't get packed?

Thanks,

Dan

Comment: Could you provide further details on your project/solution structure? How is the console app built/copied/deployed?

Comment: @SimonOpelt hi! there's a standalone project for the Console Application. I referenced this project from one of my Roles project.

Answer (score 0):

I found a hack around it via:

```
<Target Name="CopyAppConfigs" AfterTargets="CopyWorkerRoleFiles">
  <Copy SourceFiles="<path to config>" DestinationFolder="$(WorkerRoleOutputDir)" OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true" />
</Target>
```

But I am curious to see anyone else has found a proper solution for this.